# Issue with attempting to replace odd characters with 'é'

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding

Is there any problem with this update I am trying to run? When I run it, it says the relevant amount of rows have been updated but nothing actually changes:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE a
SET a.name = REPLACE(a.name, 'Ã©', 'é')
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.userID = b.userID

--ROLLBACK
--COMMIT
```

I am wondering if SQL Management Studio is not able to read the characters perhaps? I have seen nothing online to confirm this however.

Comment: run this and check if it getting displayed : `SELECT a.name , REPLACE(a.name, 'Ã©', 'é')
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.userID = b.userID`

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(a.name, 'Ã©', 'é') FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON 
    a.userID = b.userID This returns the data exactly how I would like it too.... Not sure why my update is not working with this in mind

Comment: I guess I could save how the data returns into a temp table and then set a.name = b.name from that select I have just run

Comment: What is the exact data type of `name`? if `varchar`, I would suggest using `alter table` to convert that to `nvarchar`. Then try the update again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(a.name, 'Ã©', 'é') AS name 
INTO temp_new 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.userID = b.userID
```

I then just ran this update which has resolved

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE a
SET a.name = tmp.name
FROM table1 a
JOIN temp_new tmp
ON a.userID = tmp.userID

--ROLLBACK
--COMMIT
```